# New recaptcha for my forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

As I am doing a public website, I would like to secure my public forms, beginning with the register form.

I've noticed the new Google captcha and would like to use it in my Django project.

1. Install this tool: https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha : OK
2. Add the var and the app in settings.py: OK
3. Add the script JS to the page: OK
4. Edit the class in the form to add the captcha: OK
5. Add the captcha to the form: OK

Now the new captcha is loaded properly, but I don't know how to check if it's OK or not.

Reading the documentation, it seems to be this section:

```
import os
os.environ['RECAPTCHA_TESTING'] = 'True'

form_params = {'recaptcha_response_field': 'PASSED'}
form = RegistrationForm(form_params) # assuming only one ReCaptchaField
form.is_valid() # True

os.environ['RECAPTCHA_TESTING'] = 'False'
form.is_valid() # False
```

I don't understand how this can work with my code. Moreover, I understood that the forms checks are done in the class form (clean def), not the view, so I'm confused.

forms.py:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=30, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    password_check = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password_check = cleaned_data.get('password_check')

        # Username
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            msg = "Ce nom d'utilisateur n'est pas disponible"
            self.add_error('username', msg)

        # Email
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            msg = "Cet email est déjà associé à un utilisateur"
            self.add_error('email', msg)

        # Password
        if password_check != password:
            msg = "Le mot de passe et sa confirmation doivent être identiques"
            self.add_error('password_check', msg)

        return cleaned_data
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username'].strip().capitalize()
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']

                #Success message
                messages.success(request, "Votre inscription est désormais terminée. Connectez-vous pour démarrer l'aventure.")

                return redirect(reverse('membres.views.login'))

        else:
            form = RegisterForm()

        return render(request, 'membres/register.html', locals())
```

Comment: Shameless self-plug, but if you'd like something much easier to implement, give django-simple-math-captcha a try: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-math-captcha/1.0.5

Comment: Hi, I am not really interested in math captcha. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm using django-recaptcha and I don't have to do anything to test if the captcha is good. It's handled in the form `is_valid()` method.

Comment: So I have nothing else to do? The way I did is ok and finished?

Comment: Well, you should test it and see, right? You could watch what happens during `is_valid()` or get the error value on the template.

Comment: I tried and got an error: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'